# Python project structure for selenium test

Tags: python, testing, selenium

I'm a bit rusted with Python (2.7) modules & packages so I hope to find some help. I am writing some tests using selenium. I would like to organize the tests by "scenario families" and I'd like to implement a helper class to handle some boilerplate that would be my base class for all the tests. 
Basically I'd like to have a structure looking like:

```
.
├── assets
│   └── ressource.ext
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── user
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── upload.py
│   └── visitor
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── homepage.py
│       ├── login.py
│       ├── search.py
│       └── signup.py
└── utils
    ├── __init__.py
    └── base.py
```

I am completely stuck on how to make the `utils.base` module visible to e.g. the `tests.visitor.signup` module **and** still allow to run this specific test using `python tests/visitor/signup.py`.
How would I do that?

Thanks!

Edit: to make things easier here is a dummy sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
mkdir -p {utils,tests/user}
touch {utils,tests{,/user}}/__init__.py

echo -e "import unittest\n\nclass Base(unittest.TestCase):\n    pass" > utils/base.py
echo -e "from utils.base import Base\n\nclass MyTest(Base):\n    pass\n\nif __name__ == '__main__':\n    unittest.main()" > tests/user/upload.py
```

This produces the following tree with empty `__init__.py` files and the import I'm trying to achieve in tests/user/upload.py:

```
dummy/
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── user
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── upload.py
└── utils
    ├── __init__.py
    └── base.py
```

Now if I am in the `dummy/` folder I am getting this:

```
(env)dummy  $ python tests/user/upload.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/user/upload.py", line 1, in <module>
    from utils.base import Base
ImportError: No module named utils.base
```

But if I run it interactively there is obviously no problem:

```
(env) dummy  $ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jan 16 2014, 16:39:48) 
>>> from utils.base import Base
>>>
```

My problem must be really silly but I can't see what I'm doing wrong. And what I don't get also is that specifying the python path (`(env) dummy $ PYTHON_PATH=. python tests/user/upload.py`) doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set PYTHONPATH to search the current directory:

```
PYTHONPATH=. python tests/user/upload.py
```

Or you can use a test runner, like nose:

```
nosetests tests/user/upload.py
```

Or you can create your own test runner if you don't want to use [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). For instance a `runtests.py` file with:

```
import unittest
from tests.user.upload import *
unittest.main()
```

Then:

```
python runtests.py
```

This test runner could import more tests or could be selective about what tests it imports. Ultimately, I'd recommend using nose over writing your own test runner.

Starting a test runner at the top of your hierarchy works because Python adds the current directory of a script to the list of paths it searches for modules.

Comment: Thanks for your help Louis. I haven't practice Python for quite some time but don't recall having had this issue. I added a simple way to produce my code layout if you'd like to give a try

Comment: Sorry, I think yesterday I accidentally ran `nosetests` on the mock hierarchy I created rather than just `python`. Force of habit. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Ok I was just silly when I said that passing the PYTHONPATH to the python command did not work; an import was just missing. And you're right, nose is just the good solution.